# What is aggregates?

Tags: architecture, software-design

I have read the word aggregates many times while reading domain driven design and in some software engineering articles and still, don't know how to use it or understand it properly. Sometimes I call it on Models (classes) and sometimes I miss-up with the aggregation relationship in object-oriented. Is there a good explanation?

Answer (score 2):

Both are different.
In domain driven design, a **Bounded Context** contains one or more aggregates. Splitting a bounded context into multiple aggregates is coming from the functional requirements.

An aggregate contains collection of *classes*(see note) and they are functionally related to each other. In other words, the classes in an aggregate shares same transaction (should be saved together in database).

> *Example*: **Order** class, **OrderItems** class, **OrderType**
>   Enum-Class, **Address** class.

The above four items can form an aggregate. In this case, **Order** class acts as Aggregate Root, which must be public and exposed to other layers. Only one aggregate root per aggregate.

Interaction among the aggregates are linked via only aggregate roots.

For further reading: https://domainlanguage.com/ddd/

> **Note:** *classes* - An aggregate may contain 3 categories of components. They may or may not be class types.
>
> 1. Entities - All entities are classes
> 2. Value Objects - It can be a ValueType (it could be a structure in C#)
> 3. Enum Classes - Simple enums are bad in domain driven design, so an Enum-class is preferred.